# Can not connect to another container when ports map to different ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two services running in Docker containers. When the ports map to the same ports,
i.e. `9120:9120` and `9121:9121`, then everything works correctly.

However, the containers can not connect to each other when the ports map to different port numbers as shown in this Docker compose file:

```
  version: "3.9"
  networks:
    service_net:
      name: service_net

  services: 
    base_service:
      build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: base_service/Dockerfile
      networks: 
        - service_net
      image: base_service
      container_name: base_service
      ports:
        - "19120:9120"
      restart: unless-stopped

    # The second_service uses base_service
    second_service:
      build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: second_service/Dockerfile
        args:
          BASE_SERVICE_HOST: base_service
          BASE_SERVICE_PORT: 19120
      networks: 
        - service_net
      image: second_service
      container_name: second_service
      ports:
        - "19121:9121"
      restart: unless-stopped
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

The numbers in the ports line mean the following:

```
    ports: 
    - <port-as-known-on-localhost>:<port-as-known-inside-the-docker-compose-network>
```

If you do this:

```
    ports:
    - 444:555
```

Accessing the container from the host where the containers are running on should be done on port 444

Accessing the container from another container inside the compose-network should be done on port 555

Answer (score 0):

The containers them self **and other containers in the same network**, will see the
internal ports.

In this example, all containers running in `service_net` have access to  9120 and 9121. To fix the problem, change `BASE_SERVICE_PORT` to 9120 in the Docker compose file.

I fell into this trap and only figured out what was wrong after a debug session. This fact could be described better
in [docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) in my opinion.